# Resize width and height of images

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have content stored in mysql, as following:

```
<table width="450" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><img width="513" height="680" align="left" alt=" src="/userfiles/image/pic.jpg" /></td>
            <td><img width="315" height="700" align="left" alt=" src="/userfiles/image/DSC_0389.JPG" /></td>
            <td><img width="580" height="320" align="left" alt=" src="/userfiles/image/ktxh.jpg" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I load from db, PHP and display in html by PHP, there is no problem.

Now, I want all images, be displayed by fixed width and height as 200 X 200 AND TABLE BORDER = '0'

```
<table width="200" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><img width="200" height="200" align="left" alt=" src="/userfiles/image/pic.jpg" /></td>
            <td><img width="200" height="200" align="left" alt=" src="/userfiles/image/DSC_0389.JPG" /></td>
            <td><img width="200" height="200" align="left" alt=" src="/userfiles/image/ktxh.jpg" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: $content in mysql is: &lt;table width=&quot;450&quot; cellspacing=&quot;1&quot; cellpadding=&quot;1&quot; border=&quot;0&quot;&gt;
    &lt;tbody&gt;
        &lt;tr&gt;
            &lt;td&gt;&lt;img width=&quot;513&quot; height=&quot;680&quot; align=&quot;left&quot; alt=&quot;&quot; src=&quot;/userfiles/image/pic.jpg&quot; /&gt;&lt;/td&gt;  .........etc....
           ;&lt;/table&gt;

Comment: You may try HTML parser or REGEX on $content.

Comment: i tried, but can't result: $newWidth = 200;
$newHeight = 200;

$content = preg_replace(
   array('/width="\d+"/i', '/height="\d+"/i'),
   array(sprintf('width="%d"', $newWidth), sprintf('height="%d"', $newHeight)),
   $content);

Answer (score 0):

Replace with this code and css

```
<style>
 .cstm
 {
   width:200px;
   height:200px
 }
 table
 {
  border:0
 }
</style>

<table width="200" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><img class="cstm" align="left" alt=" src="/userfiles/image/pic.jpg" /></td>
            <td><img class="cstm" align="left" alt=" src="/userfiles/image/DSC_0389.JPG" /></td>
            <td><img class="cstm" align="left" alt=" src="/userfiles/image/ktxh.jpg" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: oh no, can't  hard assign by css. the $content it be read from mysql ($child_article[6]) and display in html by dynamic code:  $sql_article = "select * from articles where approved=1 and article_cat = {$child[0]} {$article_cat_sql} order by timestamp DESC";
@$childResult_article = general_query($sql_article);  if ($child_article = mysql_fetch_row($childResult_article))  echo decode_data($child_article[6]). the  problem are replace width and height by 200x200.

Comment: i can't do it, because $content always dynamic, can 10 images, can 501 images, .... i want read $content from mysql by php and replace  width and height of all images by 200 x 200 then echo $content to website

Answer (score 0):

As you mention the $content is dynamic, can you try adding the style to the table as such:

```
 <style>
 table td>img
 {
   width:200px;
   height:200px
 }

</style>
```

Comment: the table, user create from fckEditor then save to db. So how can i adding the style to the table by php?

Comment: Not sure for php, but you can use jQuery or JavaScript to do so. For exp:
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").css({"width": "200px", "height": "200px"});
});
</script>

Comment: thank  Eddarina. But with this, it effect all images in website

Comment: i want reset all width and height to 200 x 200 in $content string before print to html.

Comment: anynone can help me

Comment: Can you open a div to put the $content? Like <div>$content </div>

Comment: or anything that can put something like class or id bfr you use the $content?

Comment: i add code below and it fix all ok :  $summary=preg_replace("/border=/",'border="0"',$row_summary);
  $summary=preg_replace("/width=/",'width="200"', $summary);
  $summary=preg_replace("/height=/",'height="200"',$summary);